# opencv stream from ip camera

Tags: python, opencv3.0, rtsp, ip-camera

im working with opencv3.4 in python 3.6
and i am trying to capture rtsp stream from my ip camera 
code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("http://admin::Admin123@192.168.0.10/cgi-bin/mjpeg?stream=1")

    while (cap.isOpened()):

        ret, frame = cap.read()     
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        k = cv2.waitKey(1)


        if k == 27:
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

i had successfully manage to get the stream and display it but if i exit the script and try to run it again i get BSOD (windows blue screen of death)

my suspicion is that opencv release method doesn't manage to release the rtsp connection

someone had this problem and manage to fix it?
thank you !!